# Filter Json item in Php

Tags: php, json

I want to filter the following JSON using a term passed by an Ajax Call

```
{"comuni":[{"datapresub":"08/08/2018","datasub":"01/02/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO AL MONTE","provincia":"SA"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO SESIA","provincia":"NO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMAGNESE","provincia":"PV"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANA","provincia":"SS"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANENGO","provincia":"CR"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO CANAVESE","provincia":"TO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO D'EZZELINO","provincia":"VI"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANO DI LOMBARDIA","provincia":"BG"},{"nomeComune":"ROMANS D'ISONZO","provincia":"GO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMBIOLO","provincia":"VV"},{"nomeComune":"ROMENO","provincia":"TN"},{"nomeComune":"ROMENTINO","provincia":"NO"},{"nomeComune":"ROMETTA","provincia":"ME"}]}
```

If the Term used is ROMA the results should be

```
[{"datapresub":"08/08/2018","datasub":"01/02/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"}]
```

I'm using the following code but I'm not able to create a function to filter the data from JSON:

```
function pippo_action() {
    if(!empty($_GET['term'])) {
        $term = $_GET['term'];
        $request = wp_remote_get( "https://demo.ec2webdesign.com/anpr-dev/comuni.json", array(
            'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;')
        ));
        if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
        $data = json_decode( $body );

        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

The code above works fine but the results expected works only for the first item. If I choose the second item from the list I got the following result:

```
{"1":{"datapresub":"08\/08\/2018","datasub":"","nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO AL MONTE","provincia":"SA"}}
```

instead:

```
[{"datapresub":"08\/08\/2018","datasub":"","nomeComune":"ROMAGNANO AL MONTE","provincia":"SA"}]
```

is there any chance to get it modifying the php code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this string:

```php
$jsonString = <<<'TAG'
{
    "comuni": [
    {
        "datapresub": "08/08/2018",
        "datasub": "01/02/2018",
        "nomeComune": "ROMA",
        "provincia": "RM"
    },
    {
        "nomeComune": "ROMAGNANO AL MONTE",
        "provincia": "SA"
    }
    ]
}
TAG;
```

The following code should work. I've included assertions but you should probably have better logic for validation. The inline comments should explain the logic.

```php
// Decode to an object
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString, false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

// Quick sanity test
assert(property_exists($jsonData, 'comuni'));
assert(is_array($jsonData->comuni));

// The term we are searching for
$term = 'ROMA';

// Filter our array
$jsonFiltered = array_filter(
    $jsonData->comuni,
    static function ($item) use ($term) {
        assert(property_exists($item, 'nomeComune'));
        return $term === $item->nomeComune;
    }
);

// Back to JSON
$jsonResult = json_encode($jsonFiltered);
```

The value of `$jsonResult` is:

```
[
    {
        "datapresub": "08\/08\/2018",
        "datasub": "01\/02\/2018",
        "nomeComune": "ROMA",
        "provincia": "RM"
    }
]
```